# How to change Wordpress image ID's

Tags: sql, wordpress, image

Fellow Overflow friends,
When uploading an image into Wordpress, it automatically assigns an image ID. I need to change this ID. Changing it doesn't seem possible through the usual dashboard, but is there a way through PHPmyadmin, or some other means?

There must be a way to access this information in the core files and change it. I need to do this because my localhost website has issues after uploading it live: conflicting image ID's resulting in broken images.

Thank you!!

Comment: Why conflicting images? You should overwrite the older ones.

Comment: Ok, to explain more clearly: I'm using a plugin to make forms that include images. The plugin relies on Image ID's. When I import the form from my localhost to my live website, it gets imported with my local wordpress image ID's, which are different from my live website's. If I could change my local image ID's to match the live website, I wouldn't have this problem.

For now, my workaround is manually changing every image ID in my export file every time I export it, so that it matches the live website's. An obvious loss of time.

Comment: I think its the not the image id its the url of the website. Go to your database and change all your content to point to the new url rather than localhost. You can use update query and where clause with `like` condition `%localhost%` on different tables.

Comment: https://torquemag.io/2016/02/move-wordpress-from-localhost-to-live-server/ You can check step 5 specifically in this article

Comment: There is a reason you can't change the ID in the admin - it is the most crucial but of information about that image/post/etc in the whole CMS and database. The ID is the only way WP can find anything to do with your image - including all the associated information in other fields and even tables. Make a mistake and it could be messed up or even lost for ever. You should *never* try changing the ids of anything in the WP database. If you haven't set up the live version correctly this is exactly what happens, and its difficult to recover from.

Comment: My advice at this stage is to start again and put a new copy of the site that is set up correctly. If you are not sure how to do this, then use one of the plugins available... we've used the [Duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) for years. I rarely recommend using a plugin over doing it yourself if you can, but in this case you are saving yourself all sorts of hassle - it just takes a couple of minutes and you are done. Believe me, you will waste way more time trying to fix this than if you just use something like this to do a fresh copy.